# Commission in Profit and Loss

Tags: percentages

To understand this commission concept in any aptitude question has always been a burden to me.
May anyway please show me an insight view into this concept.

" By what percentage must the cost price be raised in fixing the sale price in order that there may be a profit of 20% after allowing a commission of 10% ? "

I have understood only one thing from this.
If the Marked Price ( MP ) is x. Then,

```
    The business takes place on 90% of x.
```

What should i think next in such kind of questions.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume P is production price and S is sale price.

0.9*S=1.2*P

Therefore, S=1.3333*P
It means you should sell it with %33.3333 raise in price to get %20 profit after %10 commission.